# How can I set environment variables for GUI apps in OS X Mavericks using .bash_profile?

Tags: macos, environment-variables, osx-mavericks

I know for GUI apps you need to set variables under /etc/launchd.conf. But I already have my env variables set in .bash_profile and I don't want to maintain 2 sets of env variables.

Is there a way to set environment variables for GUI applications from existing variables set in .bash_profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can source .bash_profile using lanunchd services. .bash_profile is sourced when bash is run, and this happens when opening the Terminal or connecting via ssh.

It seems this thread is of significance:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac